# Paraxial Rays and Curvature of Field

Tags: optics, visible-light, geometric-optics, lenses

In [these slides](https://www.slideshare.net/VineetPanwar4/lens-aberrations-physics-term-paper) it is stated that:

> Most optical tend to form the image on a curved surface.

Well, the thin lens imaging equation states that it maps an object plane on an image plane. Of course it is not realistic. But why? Is Curvature of Field due to non-paraxial optics? Does it appear even in case of aspherical lenses?

Answer (score 0):

That a plane is imaged to another plane is an approximation for paraxial rays. When the optical system allows oblique rays, "wide field of view", then those may not necessarily get imaged in a planar surface. In fact, the corresponding focal length of an oblique pencil of rays may vary with the angle of incidence; this is field curvature. If a wide field of view single piece homogeneous lens is well corrected then it cannot be spherical because the latter has severe spherical aberration (fuzzy focus). You need an aspherical lens, as a minimum, or one that made of a inhomogeneous dielectric such as the Luneburg lens [Lunegurg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luneburg_lens), that can compensate for the primary aberrations.

Notice that the Luneburg lens is an ideal telescope lens with a complete $4\pi$ angle of field of view but its image "plane" coincides with the spherical surface of the refractor itself. Because of its ability of ideal focusing over all direction despite its funny image surface, the lens (or rather its 2D planar version) is widely used in direction finding... In this sense the this distortion is a problem if your detector surface is planar as it is on a film but if you can afford more a complicated detector this field curvature distortion can be completely eliminated by properly segmenting your detector into sufficiently small pieces.

A well-known commercial example where this problem shows up is the Schmidt "camera", see [Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_camera).  This telescope uses a spherical mirror with a non-flat refracting thin transparent aspherical plate that acts as the corrector lens. The focal surface is curved and is almost spherical, to correct for that another field flattening *convex* lens can be placed in front of it. It is a convex lens because the oblique rays converge in a longer focal length than the paraxial ones. Most good quality amateur telescopes of wide FoV use this technique or some derivative of it.